# chrome extension - need to show the description on hover of the links as a popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

chrome extension - popup page has links. need to show the description on hover of the links as a popup to the left side of the link(means the description div will come outside of the extension wondow).(popup page has popups)

similar to vertical drop down menu...
should work in the chrome extension.

Comment: Nothing in the popup can be outside the window.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot , but its not working in chrome....

I have an idea for firefox ....

take a main div .

Take 2 more divs inside the main div both of same size and also give the positions properly.

show the links in the 1st div and the descriptions in the 2nd div...

Make the 2nd div's background =  transparent. (CSS property)

and on hover of the links show the respective description div in 2nd div in front of the links..

Try it out......

Answer (score 0):

```
<A HREF="http://www.yourdomain.com/" TITLE="Your link description">Your link text</A>
```

You need the TITLE in your links... this will display inside your popup... 
"Nothing in the popup can be outside the window." as kinlan said.